# Visual Studio (2015, 2017) Compiler Error when run in standard user context

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Hoping for some assistance with regards to Visual Studio whereby my knowledge is limited and assisting to support someone else.

When compiler is run using Visual Studio 2015 Express (and 2017) in standard user context (not as administrator), get the below error message:

```
error: cannot determine the location of the v5 comm tools folder. testing 32-bit compilation cl is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Compiling and linking the model (Visual C++).
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
"Testing 32-bit compilation"
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error generating Dymosim.
```

However, when VS is run as administrator, this error does not appear.

As far as I understand, VS should not require any elevated privileges, so stumped as to why this error occurs.

The directory where VS is located is all default, and user has modify permissions.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the "v5 comm tools" ?

Comment: Here is the solution to the [cl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800361/cl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command) issue